# Logic: unique function; chain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, logic

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are sets. Let $P$ be the set of all pairs $(A,f)$ where $A$ is a subset of $X$ and $f$ is a function $A \rightarrow Y$. Then $P$ is a poset with the following relation: $(A,f) \leq (B,g)$ iff $A \subseteq B$ and $f$ is the restriction of $g$ to $A$.

Show that, if $C= \{ (A_i,f_i) |i \in I \}$ is a chain in $P$, there is a unique function $f: \cup_{i \in I}$ $A_i \rightarrow Y$ such that for each $i$, $f_i$ is the restriction of $f$ to $A_i$.

I've got some vague ideas to solve this problem, such as the use of induction on the chain (to obtain the function in different steps of expansion) and a proof by contradiction for the uniqueness of the function (if it was not unique, then it already was in some step of the induction, which gives us a contradiction). But somehow i'm struggling to make a correct  mathematical proof out of this.

Any help would be welcome and much appreciated!

Comment: Induction is neither necessary nor possible, since one cannot assume well-ordering. Let $a$ be in the union. Then $a\in A_i$ for some $i$. Define $f(a)$ as $f_i(a_i)$. Now use the chain part to observe that $f$ has been well-defined at $a$, that is, it does not depend on the $i$ that we used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The trick is to figure out first what $f$ has to be. Think of the functions as sets of ordered pairs: $f_i\subseteq A_i\times Y$. Note that if $\langle A_i,f_i\rangle\le\langle A_j,f_j\rangle$, then not only is $A_i\subseteq A_j$, but also $f_i\subseteq f_j$. Let $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, and similarly let $f=\bigcup_{i\in I}f_i$; now you need only prove that $f$ is a function with domain $A$ and that $f\upharpoonright A_i=f_i$ for each $i\in I$, which is fairly straightforward.